# Whats wrong with this Async HystrixCommand?

Tags: asynchronous, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix, hystrix, spring-cloud-sleuth

I need to send notifications from time to time, I perform this task asynchronously. I'm using HystrixCommand as below to perform an asynchronous RestTemplate call which is not working:

```
@HystrixCommand
    public Future<String> notify(final Query query) {
        return new AsyncResult<String>() {
            @Override
            public String invoke() {
                String result = null;
                try {
                    ResponseEntity<HashMap> restExchange = restTemplate.exchange(url,
                            HttpMethod.POST,
                            new HttpEntity<String>(mapper.writeValueAsString(queryMap), httpHeaders),
                            HashMap.class);
                    LOGGER.info("Response code from " + url + " = " + restExchange.getStatusCodeValue());
                    result = ""+ restExchange.getStatusCodeValue();
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception while sending notification! Message = " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                return result;
            }
        };
    }
```

This is what I was trying to do earlier(which didn't work either):

```
@HystrixCommand
    public String notify(final Query query) {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                try {
                    ResponseEntity<HashMap> restExchange = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST,
                            new HttpEntity<String>(mapper.writeValueAsString(queryMap), httpHeaders), HashMap.class);
                    LOGGER.info("Response code from " + url + " = " + restExchange.getStatusCodeValue());

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    LOGGER.error("Exception while sending notification! Message = " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }

            }
        }).start();
    }
```

P.S: Reason for adding sleuth to the tags is, performing this in a new Thread does not propagate the headers(baggage-*) so trying this hoping the Hystrix command will do the trick

Comment: Can you paste what you initially were trying to do?

Comment: I think you might be using the future wrong, don't you have to execute it explicitly? Not so much experience with Future, usually use CompletableFuture.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak I had the entire method wrapped in a runnable and was calling start() in-place. Never worked, I will edit the question with the earlier code, meantime, do you see anything that I can do to execute the async HystrixCommand, the control does not even enter the invoke method.

Comment: You know that it has to be wrapped in a `TraceRunnable` ?

Comment: Also I assume that RestTemplate is a bean? This example is so thread dependant that without debugging it I can't say much unfortunately. Maybe it's related to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/612 ?

Comment: @Jeff No, Spring Cloud uses Hystrix-javanica which takes care of executing the HystrixCommand be it execute, queue etc

Comment: `I had the entire method wrapped in a runnable and was calling start()` <-- I'm referring to that.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak No, I am not aware about the TraceRunnable. Yes, RestTemplate is a LoadBalanced bean that is autowired. I edited the question to show you my previous code.

Comment: Spring doesn't execute the HystrixCommand, it wraps it when the method is executed.

Comment: It's written in the docs - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_runnable_and_callable

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Thanks for the docs link, going through it. I am able to propogate the baggage- headers in all my other calls, I am sure it will be propgated if I can make that Async Hystrix Command execute, the problem is, the control never reaches the code inside the async HystrixCommand.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak Just a FYI, the headers are propogated when I use a plain Spring injected ThreadPool TaskExecutor without the need for wrapping it in any Traceable. I am assuming the HystrixCOncurrencyStrategy automatically propogates these headers without the intervention of Sleuth?

Comment: Yes - that's what the strategy does. Maybe when doing the combination that you have in this sample we're not delegating a call properly in the strategy and it's not working fine.

Comment: @MarcinGrzejszczak  Wrapping it with TraceRunnable worked for me, thanks for the pointer. If you can put that in the answer I will accept it. Though not sleuth related, you have any idea why my initial code within the '@AsyncResult'  never got executed?

Comment: @Jeff Spring may not execute it directly, the one responsible for the execution is: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/tree/master/hystrix-contrib/hystrix-javanica

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the method notify being called from a method in the same class? If that is the case, try calling the method notify directly from a different class where the notify method's enclosing class is injected as a dependency.

**Basically, try doing this:**

[image]

**Instead of this:**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When using `Runnable` you have to wrap them in a trace representation. i.e. `TraceRunnable`. It's there in the docs - http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-sleuth/spring-cloud-sleuth.html#_runnable_and_callable .

As for why the Hystrix stuff doesn't work - most likely it's related to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/612 .

Comment: @marcun Confirmed that the issue is not because of sleuth,  I removed the sleuth dependency from the service, still the control does not enter the 'invoke' method  of the AsyncResult .